# How to combine image embeddings with the image's dominant color values?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, vectorization

See, I have two arrays with shaped (2048,) and (3,). Is there any way to combine two of these? Don't just concatenate. All values from (2048,) should have the effect of values from (3,). What I actually mean is that my image embeddings are extracted using the -2th layer of a pre-trained ResNet50 model and the embeddings are of shape (2048,). I have extracted the dominant color of the image and their RGB values are in the array (3,): Example - [174 153 143]. So to make the image embeddings more representative of the image, I would like to connect those two. Any idea?

I tried to research about this, but all I get is to just concatenate which makes no sense in this context.